# sqlite3.OperationalError: table book has 6 columns but 5 values were supplied

Tags: python, sqlite

Getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "frontend.py", line 2, in <module>
    import backend
  File "/Users/egonsaks/Desktop/Demo/backend.py", line 28, in <module>
    insert("The sea", "John Tablet", 1918, 987654331)
  File "/Users/egonsaks/Desktop/Demo/backend.py", line 15, in insert
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO book VALUES (NULL,?,?,?,?)",(title, author, year, isbn))
  sqlite3.OperationalError: table book has 6 columns but 5 values were supplied
```

I want id column with primary key integer while inserting data in the table in the database. I checked my code against the tutorial and looked around in stack overflow for a solution from similar problems, but didn't find a solution. Tested some things like removing a null, but then it says 6 columns and 4 values were supplied.

Code here:

```
import sqlite3

def connect():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("books.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS book (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    title text, author text, year integer, isbn integer)") 
    conn.commit() 
    conn.close()

def insert(title, author, year, isbn):
    conn = sqlite3.connect("books.db") 
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO book VALUES (NULL,?,?,?,?)",(title, author, year, isbn))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error you are having on my system with the code you have.

Comment: Are you sure the book table in your database matches that schema? There's not some older version in it left over from an earlier attempt that the `IF NOT EXISTS` is covering up?

Comment: Thanks, @Shawn. It was so, deleting old db file and running program again helped and solved the problem.

Answer (score 7):

Please specify your columns when inserting, this is important, and yes do not include a `NULL` or any value for the `id` column!

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO book(title, author, year, isbn) VALUES (?,?,?,?)",
                             (title, author, year, isbn))
```

Comment: A null value for an `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` column makes sqlite auto assign a value for the column.

Comment: you can also leave it blank and it will do the same