# how to fill the sq database at different times

Tags: python, sqlite

i want to some of the column of sqlite darabase through one gui window  and the rest through another however am getting error

```
c.execute('INSERT INTO information VALUES(:name,:branch,:reg)',

sqlite3.OperationalError: table information has 6 columns but 3 values were supplied
```

Comment: The error is pretty explicit, the table has 6 fields and you provide only 3, sand the 3 missing have no default value so you have to provide them

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54198481/sqlite3-operationalerror-table-book-has-6-columns-but-5-values-were-supplied

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sqlite3.OperationalError: table book has 6 columns but 5 values were supplied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54198481/sqlite3-operationalerror-table-book-has-6-columns-but-5-values-were-supplied)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I create table dynamically on the fly and populate it:

```
def create_table(ptbl):

    """ Assemble DDL (Data Definition Language) Table Create statement and build
        sqlite3 db table

    Args:
        string: new db table name.

    Returns:
        Status string, '' or 'SUCCESS'.
    """
    retval = ''
    sqlCmd = ''
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(sqlite_file)
        c = conn.cursor()

        if ptbl == 'TBL_EXAMPLE':
            sqlCmd = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ' + ptbl + ' (FIELD1 TEXT, FIELD2 INTEGER, FIELD3 TEXT, ' \
                                                            'FIELD4 TEXT, FIELD5 TEXT)'
        else:
            pass

        if sqlCmd != '':
            c.execute(sqlCmd)
            conn.commit()
            conn.close()

        retval = 'SUCCESS'

    except Error as e:

        retval = 'FAIL'
        print(e)

    return retval
```

and the populate the table having 5 fields like this:

```
def populate_tbl_file_marker_linenums(p_fml_tbl, p_fml_datafile):
    """ Read csv and load data into TBL_FILE_MARKER_LINENUMS table ...

    Args:
        p_fml_tbl (TEXT) target table name
        p_fml_datafile (TEXT) name of csv file to load into table

    Returns:
        retval (TEXT) - Status of method, e.g., 'SUCCESS'
    """
    retval = ''
    mode = 'r'

    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(sqlite_file)
        c = conn.cursor()
        csv_dataset = open(p_fml_datafile, mode)
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_dataset)

        c.executemany('INSERT INTO ' + p_fml_tbl + ' (FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3, FIELD4, FIELD5) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', csv_reader)

        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
        retval = 'SUCCESS'

    except Error as e:
        print(e)

    return retval
```